# How to clear Java and Flash cache in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, java, flash, cache

I'd like to know how to clear Java and Flash cache in Ubuntu 16.04 using CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a clean install of Java.

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "<javaPath>"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "<javacPath>"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "<javawsPath>"
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk*
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Comment: I don't want to reinstall Java every time I want to clear the cache.

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres can you provide an example of what do you refer to as Java 'cache'?

Comment: Temporary internet files: trace, log files, cached applications and applets.

Comment: Need something more than `javaws -clearache` ?

Comment: The right command is `javaws -clearcache`

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres If you found the solution, you should post a separate answer. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer